# Spark UI does not have Executor nor Storage information

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubeflow

Running Spark 3.x cluster on kubernetes with kubeflow installed.

I am able to run spark jobs w/o issue.  During the running of the spark job, the Spark UI shows information about "Jobs", "Stages", "Environment" and "SQL".  However, the "Executors" and "Storage" tabs are blank.

The spark job is running in client mode.   The spark driver and Spark Executors are in separate pods.

I have set the following configuration parameters for the Spark job, which completes successfully.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my_spark_app") \
  .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true") \
  .config("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs:///<hdfs-location") \
  .config("spark.ui.prometheus.enabled", "true") \
  # other spark config options
```

Any suggestions on configuration parameters I may be missing or setup for kubernetes pod that may prevent viewing the "Storage" and "Executor" information.

Comment: Please check this- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html.Please check with port 4040

Comment: @Subash I have.  As I mentioned, I am able to view the Spark UI at port 4040.  I am able to see information re: Jobs, Stages, Environment and SQL.  The only information missing are Storage and Executors.  I may be missing how to either generate or collect the Storage and Executors data.